# Force Sign and Localised Thousands Separator

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Hopefully a simple answer although a web search hasn't yielded anything as of yet.

To format a number with thousands you simply use:

```
 var output = String.Format("{0:n0}", 1000000);
 // Output 1,000,000 or 1.000.000 depending on Culture
```

To format a number to always display a sign at the front you can use:

```
 var output = String.Format("{0:+0;-0;+0}", 1);
 // Output +1;

 var output = String.Format("{0:+0;-0;+0}", -1);
 // Output -1;
```

So how do I format a number with a sign and with a thousand separator?

Logically it should be this, but it doesn't work:

```
 var output = String.Format("{0:+n0;-n0;+0}", -1000000);

 // Expected output -1,000,000
 // Actual output -n10000000
```

Is there a format string that allows this and respects the current locale where the thousands separator could be a `.` or a `,`?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the section specifier [`;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SectionSeparator) with the custom specifier [`,`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierTh):

> For example, if the string "#,#" and the invariant culture are used to format the number 1000, the output is "1,000".

```
var output = String.Format("{0:+#,#;-#,#;0}", 1000000);
```

Comment: Does this reflect the current locale? For instance what if the localised thousand separator was `.` rather than `,` - this was my primary reason for wanting to use `n0`.

Comment: @CS: The linked page states: "_The NumberGroupSeparator and NumberGroupSizes properties of the current NumberFormatInfo object determine the character used as the number group separator and the size of each number group._" I tried to set German locale and got `1.000`.

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try:

```
int num = -5000000;
        Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("N0"));
```

Edit: My apologies! I was only focused on the negative symbol. Give this a shot:

```
string format = "+##,#;-##,#";
        int num = -5000000;
        int num2 = 5000000;
        Console.WriteLine(num.ToString(format));
        Console.WriteLine(num2.ToString(format));
```

Comment: This works for negative numbers but I want `+` sign displayed for positive numbers.